# JDBC physical vs logical

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

In jdbc api we mainly deal with Connection, DriverManager, Transactions.
JDBC is mainly used to connect to database and do CRUD operations. So I just need to know how each step works at lower level of JDBC.

So When we do `DriverManager.getConnection()` what happens? do it creates a session at database side? A transactions is created? What Basically a connection is?

when we do execute statements, then how database round trip happens? what is happening behind the scenes? How data is passed from java app to db and vice versa?

## update

so basically I just need to know what is happening at java side and database side on each step.

1. What does it mean by establishing a connection with database? does some sort socket is created?

Comment: Read the jdbc spec... http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-spec/jdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1442991726_ff601b99bbf7b784c0d86c72623ce6bd

Comment: @Zelldon it says unauthorised request

Comment: Ok try this https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr221/index2.html

Answer (score 1):

The exact details really depend on the driver and database. But in general: opening a connection is a relatively expensive operation so you typically want to reuse the same connection for several queries. There are also several implementations of connection pooling around (just do a little search). Opening the connection will typically establish the network connection to the DBMS (if there is a network connection; there are also in memory databases) and do the authentication of the DB user.

A connection is not the same as a transaction, you can have several transactions in one connection.

Answer (score 1):

In java you work with mainly with interfaces specified in the `java.sql` package, the class you usually deal with is `DriverManager` that allows you to get a Connection (an interface that gives you access to all the other ones ResultSet, Statement, etc). I try to give you an overview of what happens during the more common operations when working with an Oracle Database

1. `DriverManager.getConnection`: it gives you a Connection object and create a session (visibile in v$session view of the database) on the server side. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/package-summary.html) you can read that the preferred method for creating connection is to use `DataSource` that may provide connection pooling i.e. you create a fixed number of database connections (i.e. database sessions) and reuse them as needed. Connection pooling is a very welcome feature when working with Oracle databases since a connection creation is expensive (Oracle must create a remore process/thread, etc) and some of the data about sql parse (hard and soft) is kept at the connection/session level
2. create a PreparedStatement: on the server side Oracle looks at the
   SQL area if it can find the same sql and if it finds it reuses the
   access plan (i'm not going into the detail of these but building an
   access plan to the data may be a very expensive operation). If you
   want to go further you can read here a [detailed explanation](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2588723819082) of
   what happens when Oracle parses a query
3. bind the data to the preparedStatement and executing it: you pass
   the parameters to the statement and on the server side it binds the
   data to sql and execute it
4. If you are reading data from a resultSet you have a cursor on the
   server side (Oracle has provides a read only and forward only
   cursor) and when you issue a next on the resultset the same
   operation is made on the server side if you have a fetch size of 1
   on the jdbc side; otherwise the implementation may cache some
   results (which is usually a good things since with the same network
   roundtrip you can fetch more data)

This a rough overview because the topic is very broad and it depends on the detail level you need; you may face very different configurations that change what really happens on the java side.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good explanation about this topic in High-Performance Java Persistence written by Vlad Mihalcea. I try to provide a summary:

First of all, `DriverManager` requests a new physical connection from underlying driver  (establish a TCP connection to a database server). In the early version of the JDBC, it only supported the `DriverManager` utility for fetching db connections which is mainly enough for desktop application that employing a 2-tier architecture. Therefore, each user creates its own dedicated db connection. Consider that each db server can only offer a limited number of connections based on several parameters and in addition to that, establishing a db connection is a heavy operation.

In enterprise application, however، we mainly use 3-tier architecture where the middle layer acts as a bridge between user requests and data source and help us to manage the db connections in a better manner (reuse db connection). So, the application server provides logical connections instead of physical connections. The `javax.sql.DataSource` interface is a logical connections provider. In a simple word, `DataSource` delegates connection requests to the underlying `DriverManager`.
The connection request workflow could be something like this:

1. The application data layer asks the `DataSource` for a database connection.
2. The `DataSource` uses the underlying driver to open a physical connection.
3. A physical connection is created, and a TCP socket is opened.
4. The `DataSource` does not wrap the physical connection, and it simply lends it to the application layer.
5. The application executes statements using the acquired database connection.
6. When the connection is no longer needed, the application closes the physical connection along with the underlying TCP socket.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, JDBC is just an interface. What happens on database side depends on JDBC driver that is used in your application.